# Write Google Form Dynamic Content Before Submitting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-forms-api

I've been trying to search for this answer and I feel like I keep bumping up against it but can't break through.

I'm building a Google Form for a non-profit. Part of it involves filling out multiple fields where you can agree to a donation to separate funds. I would like to dynamically total those donations fields and display the total for the end user *before* they submit the form.

I can't seem to find a way in the AppScript Form API to trigger onChange of a field and get at those values (or how to write them back to the screen).

Interestingly, there is a [3rd party plugin](https://formfacade.com) that I can pay for that does it. I figured if someone else is able to do it with 3rd party code, why can't I?

I just can't figure out how they're doing it.

I've explored the App Script API and dug through a lot of previous questions. Nothing quite seems to hit this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Forms API only handles the creation of forms or what happens after submitting a form. You can’t make dynamic changes like live calculations, or using information entered on previous questions to feed new inputs and display them in the user’s view.

I played around with Formfacade, and it seemed to me that it operates from a separate environment in HTML; my guess is that the customized fields are mapped to the questions of the target form but that overall what you `see` is their visual environment, so it is not necessarily using the Forms API but a custom library for their service. Nevertheless, having the ability to work with dynamic answers in Google Forms would be a nice feature to have. If you have the time, you can open a [Feature request](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/support#developer_product_feedback)

#### References:

- [How to add a simple calculated field to a google form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29605069)
- [Google Forms triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)
- [Google Forms API REST](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest)